# AngularJS - Filtering based on value from JSON body

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a drop down box that I would like to be filtered using a response from a query.

```
$scope.retrieveUsers = function () {
    SpringDataRestService.query(
        {
            "collection": "users"
        },
        function (response) {                   // Success Function
            $scope.users = response.users;
        }
    );
};
```

This method currently retries all the users and the following JSON is this:

```
[ {
  "status" : "Dead",
  "name" : "Holy Moly"
}, {...
```

Due to the nature of the webservices, I can't use the one labelled userInternal since that is containing information not present which the users one has.

```
    $scope.userList = [];
    SpringDataRestService.get(
        {"collection": "userInternal"},
        function (response) {                   // Success Function
            var users = response._embedded.userInternal;
            for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (retrieveUsers === "PENDING_DEACTIVATION") {
                var newUser= {id: users[i].id, name: users[i].name};
                $scope.userList.push(newUser);
            }
}
        },
        function (response) {                   // Failure Function
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    );
```

So I thought an if statement would work, but I really don't know what I would use to get that function to work correctly? Any one could help? I think the rest of the code is working, it's just the actual if I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the "retrieveUsers" defined? Are you getting it with the response? If that's the case it should be "users.retrieveUsers"